# how to set image maxWidth with gatsby-image

Tags: graphql, gatsby, gatsby-image

Beginner here, I don't fully understand [gatsby-image](https://www.gatsbyjs.org/packages/gatsby-image/). I have a Gatsby template that fetches a header image from contentful with graphql. I want the header image to be fluid but I want it to have a `max-width` of the image's original size. So say if the jpg was originally 800px I don't want it to scale beyond that. I can see the graphql bit has a maxWidth property, but each image will have a different max width. I think I have to alter the way it's generating the srcset but not sure how.

in my template the relevant bits are:

```
export const query = graphql`
  query($slug: String!) {
    contentfulWork(slug: { eq: $slug }) {
      title
      heroImage {
        title
        fluid(maxWidth: 1800) {
          ...GatsbyContentfulFluid_noBase64
        }
        file {
          url
          contentType
        }
      }
    }
  }
`
```

and in the return

```
  <Img
        fluid={props.data.contentfulWork.heroImage.fluid}
        alt={props.data.contentfulWork.heroImage.title}
  />
```

The outputted code looks like this:

```
<picture>
    <source srcset="//myimage.gif?w=450&amp;h=298&amp;q=50 450w,
        //myimage.gif?w=900&amp;h=596&amp;q=50 900w,
        //myimage.gif?w=940&amp;h=622&amp;q=50 940w" 
        sizes="(max-width: 1800px) 100vw, 1800px">
 <img sizes="(max-width: 1800px) 100vw, 1800px" 
    srcset="//myimage.gif?w=450&amp;h=298&amp;q=50 450w,
            //myimage.gif?w=900&amp;h=596&amp;q=50 900w,
            //myimage.gif?w=940&amp;h=622&amp;q=50 940w"
        src="//myimage.gif?w=1800&amp;q=50" 
        alt="mygif" loading="lazy"
        style="position: absolute; top: 0px; left: 0px; 
        width: 100%; height: 100%;
        object-fit: cover; object-position: center center; 
        opacity: 1;"
    >
</picture>
```

any help greatly appreciated, thanks.

Comment: https://www.gatsbyjs.org/packages/gatsby-image/#avoiding-stretched-images-using-the-fluid-type

Answer (score 3):

[Avoiding stretched images using the fluid type](https://www.gatsbyjs.org/packages/gatsby-image/#avoiding-stretched-images-using-the-fluid-type) in the docs for gatsby-image suggests wrapping the image component like this:

```
import React from "react"
import { useStaticQuery, graphql } from "gatsby"
import Img from "gatsby-image"

const NonStretchedImage = props => {
  let normalizedProps = props
  if (props.fluid && props.fluid.presentationWidth) {
    normalizedProps = {
      ...props,
      style: {
        ...(props.style || {}),
        maxWidth: props.fluid.presentationWidth,
        margin: "0 auto", // Used to center the image
      },
    }
  }

  return <Img {...normalizedProps} />
}

const Image = () => {
  const data = useStaticQuery(graphql`
    query {
      placeholderImage: file(relativePath: { eq: "gatsby-astronaut.png" }) {
        childImageSharp {
          fluid(maxWidth: 300) {
            ...GatsbyImageSharpFluid
            presentationWidth
          }
        }
      }
    }
  `)

  return (
    <NonStretchedImage fluid={data.placeholderImage.childImageSharp.fluid} />
  )
}

export default Image
```

Comment: AH! this is extremely helpful, thank you! I tried to implement this though, and it errors out ("The fragment "GatsbyImageSharpFluidLimitPresentationSize" does not exist."), I think because GatsbyContentfulFluid_noBase64 does not have a property of presentationWidth or from the docs you linked GatsbyImageSharpFluidLimitPresentationSize... which is weird.

Answer (score 2):

This is so deep in the gatsby documents that I can't believe I wasted so much time playing around with divs.

Essentially, if you don't the fluid image to take the entire space of the parent (width/height) then you use this fragment in the graphQL query.

```
{
  childImageSharp {
    fluid(maxWidth: 500, quality: 100) {
      ...GatsbyImageSharpFluid
      ...GatsbyImageSharpFluidLimitPresentationSize
    }
  }
}
```